# Query Rule - Defining a Keyword/Action Term

Tags: search, query-rule

Unfortunately I am not understanding how to use query rules effectively.

Background: I have created a wiki page library and am using  a combination of search box webpart and search results webpart to allow users to search for articles in this wiki page library.

Issue: If someone literally types the word "email" into the search box, they will find all articles with that word present in the article.  However, it is more likely that someone will type in a phrase, such as: "I am having email issues and cannot connect." And of course, when I test a phrase such as this, i get: Nothing here matches your search."

How do I declare the word "email" as a keyword, and no matter where the keyword shows up in the user's query, it will find any and all articles in my wiki page library that have that word present within the article?

THanks so much for your help!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a query rule "Advanced Text Match" contains "email" and then change the query to "email". This will work for the specific term "email". The larger problem is that your users need to learn how to search. You may want to provide some guidance and search tips so they can begin to learn to search.

If you want to learn more about Query Rules try this: [SharePoint Display Templates and QUery Rules](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC322)

Comment: Thanks for the link to your video @Matthew.  Very Informative, and helping me out with other aspects of Query Rules as well.  I followed the example in your video, and created a query rule where "query contains action term" email, and changed the query rule to "{subjectTerms}=email."  This seems to create the keyword I need (in this case being email),

Comment: Are query rules the best way / only way to accomplish the task above?

Comment: It all comes down to your business requirements but Query Rules are probably the "best" way based on your description above. Of course you could take the time to train your users how to do basic searches.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of the search engine and cannot be altered by changing search settings.

When users enter the search term that contains multiple words (separated by space), search engine splits those words by space character and puts the AND operator between them before searching.

What you need would be the OR operator, but using the OR operator in your example, with so many words, would return very big result set, which would not be very useful.

[This article](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2222853/microsoft-subnet/10-essential-sharepoint-search-hints.html) contains very good hints for SharePoint search, where you can see how to use AND and OR operators, how to use double quotes, wildcards etc.

Comment: Are query rules the best way / only way to accomplish the task above?